# In Hinduism, is it commanded to change clothes everyday?

Tags: belief, philosophy, karma, practice, culture

If we wear the same clothes for more than a day, is it unclean according to the culture? I know in general, that one should change his clothes everyday if possible, but what does our culture say regarding this matter?

Comment: After one wear most clothes will get impure. Silken, woolen clothes are exceptions.

Comment: Keep one thing in mind that Lord only sees heart and soul (inner beauty) not body, clothing(outer beauty).

Comment: @vishvam still dehashudhi is very important in spirituality